# Sorting array and output result using var_export()

Tags: php

I have p.e. the next array and I must sort it and then outputs the result using var_export().

```
 $array = [
     'hello',
     'internet',
     'people'
 ];
```

The code should follow 2 criteria (the 2nd one is used in case the first results in a draw):

- 1st criterion is the number of vowels (aeiou) in the string. A string with more vowels should come first.
- 2nd criterion is the alphabetical order of the reversed string (hello -> olleh). Order it from "a" to "z". (ASCII sort, just like the one implemented by strcmp())

With the test data $array presented above the expected result would be:

```
 array('people', 'internet', 'hello')
```

Any idea?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17364127/how-can-i-sort-arrays-and-data-in-php

Comment: No, it's not the same problem.

Comment: It _explains_ how you can sort arrays using your own custom comparison function. So, go write your own custom comparison function that compares two elements using the criteria you specified.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Sorting an array is really easy but to do var_export() and two criterials i don't know to do it. Sorry, I'm new in php.

Comment: @MartaPascal did you write a function that compares 2 strings with your criteria (number of vowels and reverse thingy) ?

Comment: Even the “two criterials” part is already covered in main answer of the duplicate, under “Sorting by multiple fields”.

Comment: @Cid, i don't know to do it

Comment: Did you write a function that counts the number of vowels in a string ? This may be a good start

Comment: BTW, its a good question for interview! To test fresher's logic implementation ability!

Answer (score 0):

You can view your desired output by "array_reverse" function.

```
<?php
  $array = [
   'hello',
   'internet',
   'people'
  ];
  $newArray = array_reverse($array,true);
  var_export($newArray);
?>
```